# I can not access my git project via Eclipse, after commit

Tags: android, eclipse, git, github

I am new to github and I'm doing a project which is hosted on github.

But at the last(perhaps before) commit I made ​​a mistake.

And now I can not access all my files via Eclipse..
I can not figure out where this problem is!!

**This my project from Eclipse**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbru7.png

**Here is a .rar file of the project:**

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01777472951924421639&gk=hotel

Comment: To see raw-folder and current git status see: http://i40.tinypic.com/335a1d2.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Delete the gen folder
Use project > clean
Properties > android tools > fix project properties

Comment: hmm can´t get it to work.. maby I just has to manuel copy all the files into a new project :(

Comment: This is the error I now get: Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'diasporawebclient'.